# How to decrypt password value in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element

My problem is when i enter password in zend password element it show in bullet sign(encrypted formate) and when i inspect that in chrome or Mozilla it show password in plain text.how can i encrypt password at zend element like gmail password text box i mean when i type password and inspect that password it does not show my password in plain text format.

my password element in zend form is:

```
$password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('Password');

$password->setRequired(true)
        ->setAttrib('size', 30)
        ->setRenderPassword(true)
        ->addFilter('StripTags')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
    ->addValidator('StringLength',false,array('min' => 6,'max' => 50,                          

'messages' => array(
    Zend_Validate_StringLength::INVALID =>'Please Enter correct Password',
    Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_LONG =>'Password is too long',
    Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_SHORT =>'Password is too short')));;
    $password->class="textbox";
    $password->setDecorators($decorators);
    $password->setAttrib('Maxlength', 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have this problem because of the `setRenderPassword(true)` syntax. If you remove it, it will not have the password as plain text.

Comment: Thank Octav yes you'r right but if i remove them after post back they will not contain value. do you have any alternate way to do that?

Comment: I wouldn't use the `setRenderPassword` option. I think it's more secure to leave it empty than showing the filled in password after post back.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your password element is a little busier then it really needs to be.

- You never want to see or display a password, you don't care what the value is all you care about is that the inputted password value hashes to the value in your database.
- Remove the `'max'` value in the validator, you don't care how long the password is as long as it has a minimum length (your going to hash the password to a specific length anyway).
- Remove the `INVALID` message, this is not the place where you will validate the password (that happens in your auth() functions), all this validator does is validate the format.
- Again remove the `MaxLength` attribute - you don't care how long the password is, let them use the first chapter of Moby Dick if it makes the user feel better.
- Be careful about the filters you use in your password element because if you ever change or remove them you'll probably break most of the password hashes in your database. Also if the implementation of those filters ever change, that could break your hashes as well.

```
    $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Password('Password');   
    $password->setRequired(true)
             ->setAttrib('size', 30)
             ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')
             ->addValidator('StringLength',false,array('min' => 6,                           
                'messages' => array(       
                    Zend_Validate_StringLength::TOO_SHORT =>'Password is too short'
              )));;
    $password->class="textbox";
    $password->setDecorators($decorators);
```

Now you take the value of 'Password' dump it into your hashing function and either save it or compare it.

Good Luck!

Comment: is your server really that slow? Your choice.